# fopen returns null and perror prints invalid argument

Tags: c, fopen, file-handling

I created a file named "test" but I'm unable to open it using fopen.
Here is the code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Error: Invalid argument
```

What could be the reason? When does perror return "Invalid argument" error message?

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, you could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what is really happening....

Comment: Works fine for me! Also don't forget to include `#include <stdio.h>` otherwise `FILE` type is unknown

Comment: check whether the file extension(.txt) is same as that in the program

Comment: On Windows, you cannot have several processes reading and writing the same file simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`man fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html):

> EINVAL The mode provided to fopen(), fdopen(), or freopen() was invalid.

Probably `test.txt` is not readable.

Comment: But `"r"` is a *valid* mode.

Comment: As I understand [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) & [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), `errno` should be `EACCESS` in that particular case, at least on Posix.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with -g.  This lets you use gdb to debug the program step by step; look up how to use it. Probably a better way of doing this is with stat(2).  Here is a sample of code that will return an error if the file does not exist, or is not a regular file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct stat s;

  int check = stat("test.txt", &s);
  if(check != 0){
    printf("ERROR: File does not exist!\n");

    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Stat stores a lot of information about a file (such as lenght, type, etc.) in the `struct stat`, which in this case is named "s".  It also returns an integer value, which is non-zero if the file does not exist.

Comment: If you do `stat` followed by `open` there is a tiny window of time between these two calls when filesystem contents may change. The correct way is to do `open` and on failure inspect `errno`.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention: I think stat only exists on POSIX systems, not Windows and such.