# What are the possible reasons to have an error 22 with _tfopen?

Tags: c++, fopen

I provide an application developed with Visual C++ to a client and this application works well on my environment. Unfortunately, my client gets an error 22 when `_tfopen` is call.

Here is a little snippet who is similar to the code I wrote in this application:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "tchar.h"

FILE* fp;

int openFile(const TCHAR* p, const TCHAR* r)
{
    errno_t err = 0;

    fp = _tfopen(p, r);
    if (!fp)
    {
        err = errno;

        _tprintf(_T("Error %d, can't open file: %s with rights %s"), err, p, r);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All is ok\n");
    }
    return err;

}

int main()
{
    openFile(_T("\\\\127.0.0.1\\hidden_folder$\\folder\\video_file.mxf"), _T("rb"));
    return 0;
}
```

My client gets:

```
Error 22, can't open file: \\127.0.0.1\hidden_folder$\folder\video_file.mxf with rights rb
```

Error 22 means `EINVAL` for Invalid arguments. But, in my case, the arguments are corrects (according to the log).
**What can be the reasons of this behavior?**

I tried a lot of things to reproduce this error: remove video_file.mxf, change the location of the file, change the rights of the file, ... It doesn't matter, I never got the error 22.

**Notes:**

- I know `_tfopen` is now deprecated, I also created a version who uses `_tfopen_s`, the problem is still there.
- It's not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735029/fopen-returns-null-and-perror-prints-invalid-argument/26735092) because, in my case, I don't have the error and I want to reproduce it (to understand how to correct it).

Comment: Try CreateFile() with GENERIC_READ and FILE_SHARE_READ and GetLastError() instead.

Comment: Try to open the file "\\\\127.0.0.1\\hidden_folder$\\folder\\video_file.mxf"" with Notepad on your client's computer and see what happens.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The file is a binary video file too big to be opened with Notepad. Also, the file can be correctly read with a video player.

Comment: @Pierre never mind if notepad can't read it, It's just to check what error message Notepad would display.

Comment: Have you shared `hidden_folder$`?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes. If the folder is not shared, I get an error 2.

Comment: @drescherjm I wanted to say my folder is correctly shared. When I try to use _tfopen in this case, I get no error at all. But, because I want to reproduce the error of my client, I tried to _unshare_ the folder. When I do that, I get an error 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the idea of @Michael and changed my source code into this one:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "tchar.h"

FILE* fp;

int openFile(const TCHAR* p, const TCHAR* r)
{
    errno_t err = 0;

    fp = _tfopen(p, r);
    if (!fp)
    {
        err = errno;

        _tprintf(_T("Error %d, can't open file: %s with rights %s"), err, p, r);

        HANDLE hFile;
        hFile = ::CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("GetLastError = %d"), GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("No error with CreateFile"));
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All is ok\n");
    }
    return err;

}

int main()
{
    openFile(_T("\\\\127.0.0.1\\hidden_folder$\\folder\\video_file.mxf"), _T("rb"));
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to continue to use `_tfopen` to get a `FILE` pointer (used a lot of time in my application) but now to use `CreateFile` to get a more precise error code. And it works very well because I got [error 1326](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-):

> The user name or password is incorrect.

So, now, I can conclude `_tfopen` can throw error 22 when it can't log into the remote file server. This error is different of the error 13 (Permission denied) because error 13 means the user is correctly logged.